# Learn to Code a PHP Form Framework

Tags: php, forms, frameworks

Have you ever seen a book, article, or tutorial specifically about PHP form framework? I'm not talking about a whole framework, but just the bits to handle form. For now, I've used Zend's form and Symfony's form, and I'm learning about how to build a framework, and stuck in the "**how to build a form framework**" part.

I've tried to read Zend's and Symfony's code, but I think it's just too big and complex, without any explanation. Do you have any recommendation, or even maybe someone mind explaining how a form framework works (or even better, how to build a form framework)?

What I've got so far:

1. I need to create an abstract form object, so all other forms in my application can be inherited from here. The form has must have at least methods for configuring and saving.
2. We need a base widget class (for form elements) and a base validator class for form elements and widgets.
3. We need to somehow connects all of the forms. This is the part that confuses me. How can I connect all that elements?

Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: What is it that you need this form framework to do? That is, what problems are you trying to solve? The wrong approach, I think, is to try and mimic what is already done -- in the sense that framework XYZ has abstract form classes and widget classes and therefore I must need those too. The fact is existing frameworks have specific reasons for those classes, driven by need. Do you know what those needs are?

Comment: there is no form framework. Zend_Form is an abstraction meant to make the form building a little more uniform, but that about it. There is no big philosophy behind, all is based on HTML form. The concept of subform is not really a concept, is just a trick, each form is actually a separate form.

Comment: Sorry, but our network (Internet) is not in a good condition right now, and I have one appointment watiting. I'll update the question ASAP - to add what i need the form framework to do. Thanks.

Comment: Can't really edit it that time :(. But the problem's solved now. Thanks for the suggestion everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created something to abstract the creations of forms in my small framework.

Basically what I have are two main classes. The element class and the element_container class.

Most of my elements extend the element class except for the form, fieldset, div, etc, (elements that contain other elements) which extend the element_container class.

This is my simple input class:

```
class acs_form_input extends acs_element {

    public function __construct($name) {

        //These propertie is declared in the parent class

        //By default the type is set to text
        $this->setAttribute('type','text');
        $this->setAttribute('name',$name);
        $this->setAttribute('id',$name);

        $this->tpl_path = 'html/forms/form_input';
    }
}
```

Since it extends the element class I just have to say what type this is and what template it will use, the process of rendering is all done in the parent class.

The element_container class is basically the same except it can hold other elements and so has a some extra processing when it's renderes (basically a loop rendering the html of the elements)

I keep this is a model so here is a simple form code:

```
 $this->form->addText('name','Nome*');
        $this->form->addText('empresa','Empresa');
        $this->form->addText('morada','Morada')->setAttribute('size','60');
        $this->form->addText('cpostal1','C. Postal');
        $this->form->addText('cpostal2','-')->setAttribute('size','6');
        $this->form->addText('loc','Localidade');
        $this->form->addText('tel','Telefone');
        $this->form->addText('fax','Fax');
        $this->form->addText('email','E-mail*');        
        $this->form->addTextArea('msg','Mensagem*');
        $this->form->addSubmit('sub', 'Enviar »');
```

Hope this gives you some idea of what to do to create your own form framework.

NOTE: I can't chain the calls to form because every 'add[element]' method returns the instance of the created element.

Answer (score 0):

I use CakePHP or Zend_Form now on various projects, and I'd never use this myself anymore, but a few years ago I wrote a relatively complete form library like you're discussing, for a little-used framework that you've never heard of.

Anyway, this is PHP4 code, but it was used in production and worked well for us. In this case, the form class itself is Abstract, you inherit it, and define your form.

The InputField class you use to help you create your forms:
http://pastebin.com/EP8ngv8E

The Webform class: 
http://pastebin.com/4kgsFFsZ

I don't advocate you actually try to use any of this. For one, you'd have to remove or emulate all the other dependencies it has (and it has many, foremost from the looks of it, the Error and Warning classes the framework used for error handling).

But I do think that if you're interested in the subject, it might be interesting to you.

Comment: Also, like most of us do, I cringe at my code from back then! Many things were just being PHP4 and the way the framework worked. But for example, method documenattion at the top of the method instead of PHPDoc?! What was I thinking!! Ah wll, that's the sign of progress I guess: Looking back and knowing how much better you'd do now.